# Grid elements don't align

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to align `<p>` element to the left and image to the right. Image won't align to the fourth column and I need to work that out.

```css
.content{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  padding: 1cm;
  height: 500px;
}

#subcontent img {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="subcontent">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6MJo1wH.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don’t see class .references in your HTML.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was missing that, but I am still wondering whether it is necessary to specify the height and also can <img> elements be aligned independently?

Comment: It looks fine. The subcontent is exactly where you said that it should be. What is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, everything is fine, I was writing the class name incorrectly, but now that I am trying to align an image in the grid, it still doesn't work. Can you explain how to align image in grid properly?

Comment: I would like to help you but you should put html and css part where img tag is visible.

Comment: I've updated the code with the image. I want that image to be aligned to the fourth column of the grid but it doesn't move, even when I use separate `<div>` for it. Can you help me with this?

Comment: 1. There's no p element, 2. If that's the case, then grid should be on #subcontent div.

Comment: Yep, I confused p element with h3 one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? your img isn't in a direct child of a grid so assigning grid-column to it won't work.

```css
.content{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  padding: 1cm;
  height: 500px;
}

.content img {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6MJo1wH.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what layout you were going for over here, but you've specified that your 4th column spans 2 rows. Making this 1 row places everything in line:

```css
.references {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  padding: 1cm;
  height: 500px;
}

#subcontent {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="references">
  <div>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>Nam volutpat pharetra velit in scelerisque. Etiam at dapibus justo. Ut porta enim massa, vel commodo nunc tincidunt eu. Sed sit amet eleifend turpis.</p>

  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>Nam volutpat pharetra velit in scelerisque. Etiam at dapibus justo. Ut porta enim massa, vel commodo nunc tincidunt eu. Sed sit amet eleifend turpis.</p>

  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>Nam volutpat pharetra velit in scelerisque. Etiam at dapibus justo. Ut porta enim massa, vel commodo nunc tincidunt eu. Sed sit amet eleifend turpis.</p>

  </div>

  <div id="subcontent">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>Nam volutpat pharetra velit in scelerisque. Etiam at dapibus justo. Ut porta enim massa, vel commodo nunc tincidunt eu. Sed sit amet eleifend turpis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```